# Json string array to object in Vuex

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, vuex

In my states I have `categories`. In the `categories` array every each category have a `settings` column where I have saved json array string. 
My question it is,how can I turn my string to object by filtering the response ?
My response:

```
[{"id":4,"name":"Vehicles","slug":"vehicles","settings":"[{"edit":true,"searchable":true}]","created_at":"2019-01-26 16:37:36","updated_at":"2019-01-26 16:37:36"},
```

This is my loading action for the categories:

```
const loadCategories = async ({ commit }, payload) => {
  commit('SET_LOADING', true);

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`admin/store/categories?page=${payload.page}`);
    const checkErrors = checkResponse(response);
    if (checkErrors) {
      commit('SET_DIALOG_MESSAGE', checkErrors.message, { root: true });
    } else {
      commit('SET_STORE_CATEGORIES', response.data);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    commit('SET_DIALOG_MESSAGE', 'errors.generic_error', { root: true });
  } finally {
    commit('SET_LOADING', false);
  }
};
```

This is my SET_STORE_CATEGORIES:

```
const SET_STORE_CATEGORIES = (state, payload) => {

  state.categories=payload.data;

  state.pagination = {
    currentPage: payload.current_page,
    perPage: payload.per_page,
    totalCategories: payload.total,
    totalPages: payload.last_page,
  };
};
```

Here I would like to add to modify the value ,to turn the string to object.
Had to add:

```
 let parsed=[];
      parsed=response.data.data.map((item)=>{
              console.log(item);
               let tmp=item;
                tmp.settings=JSON.parse(item.settings);
              return tmp;
            });
      response.data.data=parsed;
      commit('SET_STORE_CATEGORIES', response.data);
```

Comment: use `JSON.parse(yourString)` function

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim,that is clean,but I would like to this before save's to the states

Comment: please provide more details in your question

Comment: why are you doing `response.data.data=parsed;` ?

Comment: My response is a pagination response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map your response data as follows by parsing that string to an object :

```
let parsed=[];
parsed=response.data.map((item)=>{
         let tmp=item;
          tmp.settings=JSON.parse(item.settings);
        return tmp;
      });
commit('SET_STORE_CATEGORIES', parsed);
```

Comment: getting error. I guess as my response data is an array where is more cat than 1.

Comment: hat's that error? please print that response and give me the output